# Snackbar callback from another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, snackbar

I have a **Fragment (A)** with recycler view. When I press on an item, the **DialogFragment** (with details about that item) is shown. When I press delete button, the item is deleted and the fragment A is shown (with changes). My question is **how to notify that item was deleted?** I would like to show a **Snackbar** with **undo option**. I have not found anything on Google..

Thanks

Comment: since communication between fragments is recommended to be done via the activity, you could implement an interface in your dialogfragment that notifies the main activity of item deletion, which then notifies fragment A through another interface to refresh or whatever.

Comment: I've added an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define an interface in the DialogFragment:

```
public interface OnDeletedItem {
        void onDeletedItem(Item deletedItem);
    }
```

Make your activity implement the interface,

```
public class MainActivity
        extends AppCompatActivity
        implements DialogFragment.OnDeletedItem

    @Override
    public void onDeletedItem(Item deletedItem) {

            // get the Fragment A from fragment manager and notify it via public method to show a Snackbar with the Undo option as desired

FragmentA fragmentA = (FragmentA) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FragmentA");
fragmentA.showSnackbarForDeletedItem(deletedItem); // implement showSnackbarForDeletedItem or similar method in FragmentA
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    }
```

Then, when you press the Delete button in the DialogFragment:

```
try {

     ((OnDeletedItem)getActivity()).onDeletedItem(deletedItem);

    } catch (ClassCastException cce) {}
```